# Calling is_instance() does not appear to instantiate class

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I'm having an issue with developing something similar to the Django [_get_queryset(klass)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts/__init__.py#L80) method. I'm trying to pull a QuerySet when provided with either a QuerySet, or a mongoengine Document. I've tried the following logic:

```
from mongoengine.base import BaseDocument
from mongoengine.queryset import QuerySet

def _get_queryset(klass):
    if isinstance(klass, QuerySet):
        return klass
    if isinstance(klass, BaseDocument):
        return klass.objects
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

For a given Document, such as:

```
class Monkey(mongoengine.Document):
    name = mongoengine.StringField(unique=True)
```

If I pass the following in to python's [`is_instance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
>>> isinstance(db.Monkey.objects, QuerySet)
True
```

But (seemingly) surprisingly,

```
>>> isinstance(Monkey, BaseDocument)
False

>>> isinstance(Monkey(), BaseDocument)
True
```

Does `isinstance()` not instantiate the class when presented with it? In Django, a roughly equivalent call works:

```
>>> isinstance(Monkey, ModelBase)
True
```

Why does `Monkey` get instantiated here in Django, but not in the above mongoengine version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python classes are objects. In particular they are instances of `type`:

```
>>> class MyClass(object): pass
... 
>>> isinstance(MyClass, type)
True
```

Also, since `object` is the most base-type they are also instances of `object`:

```
>>> isinstance(MyClass, object)
True
```

so, the result you are obtaining is correct. An instance of a class is something different from the class itself. If you want to check whether a class is a subclass, there is the `issubclass` function:

```
>>> issubclass(MyClass, object)
True
```

The fact that in Django `isinstance(Monkey, ModelBase)` works is because in django `ModelBase` is not a class but a metaclass:

```
# from django source-code
class ModelBase(type):
    """
    Metaclass for all models.
    """
```

Which means that model classes are instances of their metaclass(in this case `ModelBase`).

Comment: So why does the Django ```isinstance(Monkey, ModelBase)``` work?

Comment: @jvc26 In django `ModelBase` is a meta-class and not a class, while in mongo this probably isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, classes themselves are objects. By default, a class is of type `type` (i.e. it is an instance of the `type` class), but that default can be overridden by using a *metaclass*. Using a metaclass will cause the class to be an instance of the metaclass (which should extend `type`).

This means that if you define a class `Monkey` with metaclass `ModelBase`, then Python will create a `ModelBase` object named `Monkey`. The `Monkey` object is a class, so you can instantiate objects of type `Monkey`.